# i can't use string replacing function in a data frame in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, google-colaboratory

i want to clean my data in a column of dataframe and omit 'k' character through it, but the function doesn't work .

the string is : '$111K-$181K (Glassdoor est.)'
when i use the function above
i can't omit the 'k'

def k_remover(a) :
a=a.replace('k','')
return (a)

Comment: The `replace` function is case sensitive. String has `K`s but you remove possible `k`s.

Comment: Hello, I'm curious as to whether you have seen my answer and whether it worked for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use lower() method and remove all the matching characters

```
def k_remover(a, char):
    a = a.lower()
    a = a.replace(char,'')
    return a
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you write these:

```py
def k_remover(a):
       a=a.replace('k','')
       return (a)
```

The problem is that you are giving upper 'K' and you are saying that remove lower 'k' instead of actual one ('K'). That is why it is not working.

```py
def remover(value, char_remove):
    ''' The value you give, char_remove is the character that should be removed'''
    result = value.replace(char_remove, '')
    return result
```

Above you can use with anything. But there is a built-in function .replace() you can also use it.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple main issues here:

One being that "replace" is case-sensitive, and in your example data, the "K" is capitalized, while the substring you are trying to replace is lowercase. You can fix this by either using an uppercase "K" or by setting the case argument to False.

Two being the need for a ".str" method in your code. This tells python/pandas that you're treating this data as a string-type variable.

Below is some dummy data and then a one-liner that should remove every "K" from the column of your choice, just change the 'column_name' to the column in your project.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()

df['column_name'] = ['$111K-$181K (Glassdoor est.)', '$200K-$250K (LinkedIn est.)']
df['column_name'] = df['column_name'].str.replace('k', '', case=False)
```